# Javascript replace whitespace with new line

Tags: javascript, replace

Is it possible in javascript to replace all whitespaces in

`<input name="product_description[2][name]>"`

and turn them into line breaks and show them in

`<textarea name="product_description[2][meta_keyword]">`

I am trying this

```
function getElements()
{
var text = document.getElementsByName('product_description[2][name]').value;
var out = document.getElementsByName('product_description[2][meta_keyword]').value;}
function makelinebreaks(){
text = text.split(" ").join("\n")
out = text;}
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Next question.

Comment: We're not here to make your homework.

Answer (score 22):

I don't really understand your HTML fragments, but to perform that operation on a JavaScript string `text`, one way is.

```
text.split(" ").join("\n")
```

Comment: Super simple soliution, +1 for that!

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#textarea").val($("#input").val().replace(/ /g, "\r\n"));
```